# How to stop ORDER BY RAND() from duplicating results?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying get 5 random places from the table places and adding a random photo (linked to it by id) to it. I have done that and it works fine using the ORDER BY RAND() but most of the times results get duplicated. I would see the same "Place" but with another random photo I put an image under to explain what I see.

Place 1 then another Place 1

Has anyone seen something like this before and can help me?
I would really appreciate it.

[image]

My PHP code:

```
/// 5 random places + 1 random photo for each place

$sqlCommand2 = "SELECT DISTINCT(places.id), places.id AS id, places.title AS title, places.latitude AS latitude , places.longitude AS longitude, places_photos.place_id, places_photos.url AS image FROM places INNER JOIN places_photos ON places.id = places_photos.place_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5";

  $query2 = mysql_query($sqlCommand2) or die(mysql_error());
  $count2 = mysql_num_rows($query2);
  if($count2 > 1){
    $places .= "";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2)){

        $places .= "<a href=\"places/p/?id=".$row['id']."\"><div class=\"main-place-item\" style=\"background-image: url('http://Ayoubsi.com/places/p/images/".$row['image']."');\"><div id=\"title\">".$row['title']."</div></div></a>";
            } // close while

  } else {
    $places = "No places!";
  }
```

---

And this is the HTML

```
<div id="main-places">
      <?php echo $places; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Use group by place title

Comment: @shivachauhan Thanks

Comment: it's okay not an issue

Comment: `distinct(column), column` is not good syntax because distinct is not a function. Distinct qualifies the keyword select, and "select distinct" works across the WHOLE ROW not just the first listed column

Comment: @Used_By_Already: yes. The `DISTINCT` keyword (following SELECT) applies to *all* of the expressions in the SELECT list. Wrapping an expression in parens doesn't violate any syntax rule. You are absolutely right... there's no good reason to wrap an expression in unnecessary parens and butt that paren up against the DISTINCT keyword. It only obfuscates the fact that DISTINCT is not a function by making it *look* like it's a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) your results instead of using DISTINCT.

Change your query to:

```
$sqlCommand2 = "SELECT places.id, places.id AS id, 
places.title AS title, places.latitude AS latitude ,
 places.longitude AS longitude, places_photos.place_id, 
places_photos.url AS image FROM places 
INNER JOIN places_photos ON places.id = places_photos.place_id 
GROUP BY places.id
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5";
```

Because even if you are using DISTINCT, you are using JOIN.

And in JOIN, duplicate results are coming.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not understanding the SQL keyword **`DISTINCT`**. That's a keyword. It's  *not* a function.

`SELECT DISTINCT` applies to *all* of the expressions in the select list, not just some column(s) wrapped in unnecessary parens.

When you write a statement like this:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT(a), b, c FROM ...
```

those parens around that first expression `a` don't do anything. That's equivalent to writing:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c FROM ...
```

The point is that the DISTINCT keyword is going to eliminate the duplicate rows. In this example, where the values of `a`, `b`, and `c` (taken together) duplicate the values of `a`, `b` and `c` returned from another row.

If you want distinct values of just the expression `a`, then use a `GROUP BY` clause.

```
  SELECT a, b, c
    FROM ...
   GROUP BY a
```

(Note that MySQL has a non-standard extension to GROUP BY that allows the expressions `b` and `c` to be non-aggregates, where other databases will throw an error. MySQL will return a value for `b` and `c` that is from one of the rows that was collapsed ("grouped") together,  but which of those rows the values will come from is not deterministic.)

Answer (score 0):

Please use "seed" in RAND() function. Like below.

```
$seed=time();

$query="SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY RAND($seed) LIMIT $amount OFFSET $offset";
```

Comment: This is just wrong. Try this statement and observe the behavior: `SELECT RAND(123), RAND(123), RAND(123)`. You'll note that the repeated calls to the the RAND function with the same "seed" value will all return the *same* value.

Comment: @spencer7593 Did you try it with time() function ?

Comment: the question is, did *you* try it? At the point it's put into the SQL text, it's a literal. And SQL is going to execute the RAND(literal) function for every row, and return the *exact* same value for every execution. RAND is a *pseudo-random* number generator. By including a literal value as an argument, that is effectively the same as specifying a literal in the `ORDER BY` clause. There's nothing necessarily wrong with doing that. But it doesn't cause the rows to be ordered in a random or pseudo random order.

Answer (score 0):

From your query I'm guessing you have multiple photos per place.

For each place, do you want to show a random one of its photos?

If not, then you can use the query

```
$sqlCommand2 = "SELECT 
                    `places`.`id`,
                    `places`.`title`,
                    `places`.`latitude`,
                    `places`.`longitude`,
                    `places_photos`.`place_id`, 
                    `places_photos`.`url` AS `image`
                FROM 
                    `places`
                        JOIN 
                            `places_photos`
                        ON 
                            `places`.`id` = `places_photos`.`place_id`
                GROUP BY `places`.`id`
                ORDER BY
                    RAND()
                LIMIT 5";
```

If you do want to select a random photo you'll need to use a subquery like so

```
$sqlCommand2 = "SELECT
                    `x`.`id`,
                    `x`.`title`,
                    `x`.`latitude`,
                    `x`.`longitude`,
                    `x`.`place_id`, 
                    `x`.`url` AS `image`
                FROM (
                    SELECT
                        *
                    FROM 
                        `places`
                            JOIN 
                                `places_photos`
                            ON 
                                `places`.`id` = `places_photos`.`place_id`
                    ORDER BY
                        RAND()
                    ) AS 'x'
                GROUP BY
                    `x`.`id`
                LIMIT 5";
```